# Preposition with emphasis

Tags: prepositions

> - Our Physics teacher often emphasizes ***on*** the end for a lot of
>     practice.
> - Our Physics teacher often emphasizes the end for a lot of
>     practice.
> - Our Physics teacher often emphasizes ***upon*** the end for a lot of
>      practice.

What is difference and which is/are correct.

Comment: What is “the end” in this context?

Comment: @Mixolydian I guess OP means **at** the end of the lecture!

Comment: None of the sentences make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples makes sense. Perhaps you mean:

> *At the end of a lecture* our Physics teacher often emphasizes *the need* for a lot of practice.